# separate text and numbers and convert to dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list like this:

```
[['fast_ema_period=22', ' slow_ema_period=10', ' signal_period=34', ' StopLoss=190', ' TakeProfit=140', ' Slippage=1', ' MagicNumber=0', ' '],

['fast_ema_period=4', ' slow_ema_period=22', ' signal_period=14', ' StopLoss=180', ' TakeProfit=170', ' Slippage=1', ' MagicNumber=0', ' '],

['fast_ema_period=32', ' slow_ema_period=10', ' signal_period=24', ' StopLoss=180', ' TakeProfit=120', ' Slippage=1', ' MagicNumber=0', ' '],

['fast_ema_period=40', ' slow_ema_period=46', ' signal_period=36', ' StopLoss=40', ' TakeProfit=130', ' Slippage=1', ' MagicNumber=0', ' ']]
```

and **I would like to convert it to a pandas' dataframe** with:

columns: `[fast_ema_period, slow_ema_period, signal_period, StopLoss,TakeProfit, Slippage, MagicNumber]`

and the values in the body of the table.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why not a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# Use a default dict to make our life easier (we already know we are working with lists)
data = defaultdict(list)
# Get each item from each list, the below list-comprehension is efficient.
for item in [item for sublist in biglist for item in sublist if '=' in item]:
    key, value = item.split('=', 1)  # split the items on '=' but only once.
    data[key].append(value)  # add our new value to our dictionary. 

pd.DataFrame(data)  # tada!
```